# PL/SQL Trigger to check value before insert statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am new to PL/SQL and I have an issue regarding a trigger I am trying to implement.

The triggers purpose is to check a monetary value before it's inserted into the table to see if someone made a mistake during inserting. If they have, they will be given a message stating the value is incorrect. The values are in the billions so for now I am just checking if the value entered is above 10000 or not.

The trigger I currently have is;

```
CREATE TRIGGER Check_Value
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF "Potential Annual Value By 2026" ON AIPOTENTIALVALUEFORHEALTHCARE
BEGIN
IF (NEW."Potential Annual Value By 2026" < 10000.00) THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Value typed was incorrect');
ELSIF (NEW."Potential Annual Value By 2026" >= 10000.00) THEN
INSERT INTO AIPOTENTIALVALUEFORHEALTHCARE VALUES(NEW.ValueID, NEW.ApplicationID, NEW."Application Name", NEW.KeyDriverForAdoptionID, NEW."KeyDriverDescription", NEW."Potential Annual Value By 2026");
END IF;
END;
```

This will not work due to an error:

```
PLS-00201: identifier NEW.'Potential Annual Value By 2026' must be declared
```

My guess is that I have set the trigger incorrectly and that it doesn't know which value to check when it runs the trigger. From some research, I tried to use .NEW to pass the values of the statement into the trigger however I am not sure if this is the correct implementation.

I had tried the method already posted;

```
CREATE TRIGGER Check_Value
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF "Potential Annual Value By 2026" ON AIPOTENTIALVALUEFORHEALTHCARE
BEGIN
  IF (:NEW."Potential Annual Value By 2026" < 10000.00) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Value typed was incorrect');
  ELSIF (:NEW."Potential Annual Value By 2026" >= 10000.00) THEN
    INSERT INTO AIPOTENTIALVALUEFORHEALTHCARE VALUES
      (:NEW.ValueID, :NEW.ApplicationID, :NEW."Application Name", 
       :NEW.KeyDriverForAdoptionID, :NEW."KeyDriverDescription", 
       :NEW."Potential Annual Value By 2026");
  END IF;
END;
```

and recieved a different error:

```
ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers
04082. 00000 -  "NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers"
*Cause:    The trigger is accessing "new" or "old" values in a table trigger.
*Action:   Remove any new or old references.
```

If this error is stating I can't use NEW references in a table level trigger, how would I be able to verify the contents of the insert statement before it is committed?

Comment: And as an aside, you really, _really_, _REALLY_ don't want to be nameing columns, or any other objects, in mixed case _or_ with embedded spaces (UPDATE OF "Potential Annual Value By 2026").  Any time you find yourself having to enclose an object name in double-quotes, you need to think again.  And again.  And again.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing colons before the `NEW` keywords and the FOR EACH ROW clause.  Also you do not need to (and must not) re-issue the INSERT within the trigger, it will happen anyway (if no error is raised):

```
CREATE TRIGGER Check_Value
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF "Potential Annual Value By 2026" ON AIPOTENTIALVALUEFORHEALTHCARE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (:NEW."Potential Annual Value By 2026" < 10000.00) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Value typed was incorrect');
  END IF;
END;
```

I'm sure this is just a training example, but DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE is not a suitable method for raising errors to users as its output can only be seen when using develpper tools like SQL Developer. Use `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`.  Also it doesn't actually raise an exception, so it won't prevent the insert at all.

In fact, this check might be better done with a CHECK constraint - assuming the column value must never be under 10000:

```
ALTER TABLE AIPOTENTIALVALUEFORHEALTHCARE
   ADD CONSTRAINT AIPOTENTIALVALUEFORHEALTHCARE_CHK_VALUE
      CHECK ("Potential Annual Value By 2026" >= 10000);
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that I have already tried this method and it did not work, I will edit the post with the errors received. Yes, this is just a small play with Oracle SQL Developer for my own interest however I will look into Raise_Application_Error.

Comment: @JohnSortley24 answer updated - you need FOR EACH ROW

Comment: Thank you, I thought FOR EACH ROW was used to loop through every row in the table which is why I didn't include it. You're logic is much better for this and I will keep the insert statement in mind next time. If I add the check constraint to each field I want to validate, can I customize what error is thrown if the condition is not met? Theoretically I can name the constraint the error message right? Or is there a better way

Comment: Using [check constraint](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-check-constraint/) is way to go, when violated you will get an exception "ORA-02290: check constraint " followed by scheme name and constraint name. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=245b0a4ad7e0120067fad89b45328ef0)